# store sha256 string to db

Tags: c#, .net

I use this code to hash string

```
    static string hashPassword(string password)
    {
        SHA256Managed crypt = new SHA256Managed();
        string hash = String.Empty;
        byte[] crypto = crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(password));
        foreach (byte bit in crypto)
        {
            hash += bit.ToString("x2");
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

string is then saved to database into field 'password' data type nvarchar(max) for testing.
Problem :

when i run code

```
string password = hashPassword(maskedTextBox1.Text.ToString());
int valid = this.op_radnikTableAdapter.fLoginData(dimproDataSet.op_radnik,
                    korisnicko_ime, Convert.ToString(password));
```

int valid is always 0. When i run query in sql management studio or dataset query builder row is returned:

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 [radnik_id]
  ,[radnik_aktivan]
  ,[radnik_dimpro]
  ,[radnik_ime_prezime]
  ,[radnik_password]
  ,[radnik_korisnicko_ime]
  ,[radnik_isAdmin]
   FROM [dimpro].[dbo].[op_radnik]
   WHERE (radnik_korisnicko_ime = 'administrator' AND radnik_password = '9af15b336e6a9619928537df30b2e6a2376569fcf9d7e773eccede65606529a0')
```

password is 0000 (sha256)

fLoginData

```
    SELECT        radnik_id, radnik_aktivan, radnik_ime_prezime, radnik_password, radnik_dimpro, radnik_korisnicko_ime, radnik_isAdmin
    FROM            op_radnik
    WHERE        (radnik_korisnicko_ime = @korisnicko_ime) AND (radnik_password = @pass)
```

thanks

Comment: hashing code looks fine, my guess the problem is something simple most likely with the value you are passing for radnik_korisnicko_ime or something in fLoginData()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with new SQL SELECT STATEMENT. Statement is the same but now works, don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You have a .ToString() and a Convert.ToString that isn't needed because your password variable is already a string. Also your textbox.Text field is already a string too. I doubt that would be the issue but it's possible.

Try this:

```
string password = hashPassword(maskedTextBox1.Text);
int valid = this.op_radnikTableAdapter.fLoginData(dimproDataSet.op_radnik,
                korisnicko_ime, password);
```

Does that change anything?

What is the code for fLoginData, and what is the value of dimproDataSet.op_radnik, and korisnicko_ime at debug?

Comment: Convert.ToString is added just before asking this question ? It's same with or without convert.tostring.Edited question  with fLoginData query

Comment: values at debug are correct. Username: administrator
Password: 9af15b336e6a9619928537df30b2e6a2376569fcf9d7e773eccede65606529a0